# GeoReference use wordfile in arcgis

Tags: arcgis-10.0, gdal, google-maps, georeferencing

I have a tiff image and have the required information to Geo-reference it on the MAP. which called world file like [this](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=World_files_for_raster_datasets).

using GMAP.NEt API there are many limited functions not like the java script google map API 3.
So any hope to bind C# windows application and javascript map API ?

on other hand, from the ArcGIS link I can know the (X,Y) for each pixel from the image located at the MAP.
BUT how to do that ? is there any method to do to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

A world file is only a very simple text file so, if you have the image and the required information to create a world file as you say, then the simplest approach is to use a text editor to make the world file and give it an appropriate extension as per the ArcGIS help document you reference.  Save the world file in the same folder as the image and then simple open it in ArcGIS (but delete any existing .aux files associated with your image first or your results may be unexpected - these will only exist if you've opened the ungeoreferenced image in ArcGIS already).  If you only have one or two images and know their details, then this is the quickest and most pragmatic approach.

Comment: yes, I have read that there is approach to do that in ArcGIS,
but I need to make it from my C# application instead of ArcGIS
the GMAP API for c# hasn't the capabilities to do that!

Comment: Can't you write a simple C# script to create the world files?    If you know all the details for each file, you don't need any special API, just the ability to write to a text file.